# How can I make an image slider which makes image move right to left?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hey guys I'm making an image slider on my website and I've got the main functionality down but I want there to be a transition where you see the next image  being pulled into view instead of just appearing there. Kind of like the one on this site.

https://allisonstexasbbq.com/

Also here's a link to my website, the code posted below is incomplete because there's too much code to post here so here's my fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/0ekqLu4c/

p.s I also realized you can't see my images cause there saved to my machine. Unfortunately I don't know how to get around this.

```css
html, body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 overflow-x: hidden;
}


/*HEADER*/

.logo {
 text-transform: uppercase;
 color: white;
 font-family: 'Staatliches';
 font-size: 10rem;
 letter-spacing: 20px;
 font-weight: bolder;
 position: relative;
 left: 800px;
 top: 150px;
}

#header {
 background: url('img/mex-9.jpg');
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-size: cover;
 width: 100vw;
 height: 100vh;
}

.btn-1, .btn-2, .btn-3 {
 background-color: white;
 width: 62px;
 margin-bottom: 9px;
 height: 8px;
 border-radius: 5px;
}

.btn-1 {
 background-color: lightgreen;
 position: relative;
 animation-duration: 0.3s;
 animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes btn-1-animate {
 from {width: 62px; left: 0px; top: 0px;}
 to { top: 75px; left: -12px; width: 84px;}
}

@keyframes btn-1-reverse {
 from {top: 75px; left: -12px; width: 84px;}
 to {top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 62px;}
}

.btn-2 {
 border-radius: none;
 background-color: white;
 position: relative;
 animation-duration: 0.3s;
 animation-fill-mode: forwards;
 z-index: 1;
}

@keyframes btn-2-animate {
 from {top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 62px}
 to {top: 58px; left: 65px; width: 117px;}
}

@keyframes btn-2-reverse {
 from {top: 58px; left: 65px; width: 117px;}
 to {top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 62px;}
}

.btn-3 {
 background-color: #ff4d4d;
 position: relative;
 animation-duration: 0.3s;
 animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes btn-3-animate {
 from {top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 62px;}
 to {top: 41px; left: 180px; width: 160px;}
}

@keyframes btn-3-reverse {
 from {top: 41px; left: 180px; width: 160px;}
 to {top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 62px;}
}

.side-menu, .nav-btn {
 padding-top: 100px;
 padding-left: 50px;
}

.nav-btn {
 width: 70px;
 position: fixed;
 top: 5px;
 z-index: 10;
}

#header ul {
 border-radius: 10px;
 margin: 0;
 list-style-type: none;
 background-color: white;
 position: fixed;
 top: 200px;
 text-align: center;
 box-shadow: -15px 0px lightgreen;
}

.side-menu {
 position: relative;
 left: -2370px;
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
    z-index: 1;
}

.fa-times {
 position: fixed;
 left: -380px;
 top: 200px;
 font-size: 2rem;
 color: white;
 transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

.fa-times:hover {
 transform: scale(1.3);
 cursor: pointer;
}

#header li a {
 font-family: 'Kumar One Outline';
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 2.2rem;
 padding: 15px;
 color: grey;
 margin-bottom: 15px;

}

#header li:hover {
 transform: scale(1.15);
}
 
 #header li {
  margin: 15px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  transition: all 0.35s ease;
 }

 #header li a:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bolder;
  color: #96ea96;
 }

 #header p {
  float: right;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 3.2rem;
    margin-top: -10px;
    margin-right: 100px;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Cedarville Cursive';
 }

 /*ABOUT*/

 #about .container {
  background-color: #339966;
  width: 100vw;
  overflow: auto;
  padding-bottom: -400px;
 }

 #about h1 {
  margin-top: 0;
  font-family: 'Cedarville Cursive';
  font-size: 3.5rem;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 5px;
 }

 .line {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 0px;
  height: 4px;
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 560px;
  position: relative;
  top: 90px;
  transition: all 1s ease;
 }

 #about p {
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans';
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  width: 35%;
  margin-left: 130px;
 }

 .image-slider {
  background-color: grey;
  background-image: url(img/f-0.jpeg);
  background-position: center; /* Center the image */
  background-repeat: no-repeat; /* Do not repeat the image */
   background-size: cover; /* Resize the background image to cover the entire container */
  width: 35%;
  height: 250px;
  margin-right: 160px;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  position: relative;
  top: -380px;
  float: right;
 }

 .fa-caret-down {
  color: white;
  font-size: 4rem;
  margin-top: 29%;
  position: relative;
 }

 .left {
 transform: rotate(90deg);
 left: -40px;
 }

 .right {
 float: right;
 transform: rotate(-90deg);
 left: 40px;
 }

 .left:hover, .right:hover {
  cursor: pointer;

 }

/*MENU*/

#menu .container {
 background-color: #e6ac00;
 width: 100vw;
 margin-top: -330px;
 clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 3%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
 overflow: hidden;
}

.shape-wrap {
 position: relative;
}

.shape-1 {
 height: 0;
 border-top: 25px solid transparent;
 border-left: 50px solid #339966;
 border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
 position: relative;
 top: 50px;
 left: -190px;
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 0;
}

.shape-2 {
 height: 0;
 border-top: 25px solid transparent;
 border-right: 50px solid #26734d;
 border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
 float: left;
 position: relative;
 top: 25px;
 display: inline-block;
 left: 10px;
}

.shape-3 {
 height: 0;
 border-top: 25px solid transparent;
 border-left: 50px solid #40bf80;
 border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
 position: relative;
 left: -195px;
 display: inline-block;
 top: 25px;
}

.shape-4 {
 height: 0;
 border-top: 25px solid transparent;
 border-right: 50px solid #26734d;
 border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
 float: left;
 position: relative;
 left: -40px;
 display: inline-block;
 top: 85px;
}

.shape-5 {
 height: 0;
 border-top: 25px solid transparent;
 border-left: 50px solid #339966;
 border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
 position: relative;
 left: -298px;
 display: inline-block;
 top: 110px;
}

.shape-6 {
 height: 0;
 border-top: 25px solid transparent;
 border-left: 50px solid #339966;
 border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
 position: relative;
 top: 230px;
 display: inline-block;
 left: -351px;
}

.shape-7 {
 height: 0;
 border-top: 25px solid transparent;
 border-right: 50px solid #26734d;
 border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
 float: left;
 position: relative;
 left: -90px;
 display: inline-block;
 top: 265px;
}

.shape-8 {
 height: 0;
 border-top: 25px solid transparent;
 border-left: 50px solid #339966;
 border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
 position: relative;
 top: 290px;
 display: inline-block;
 left: -405px;
}

.shape-9 {
 height: 0;
 border-top: 25px solid transparent;
 border-right: 50px solid #26734d;
 border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
 float: left;
 position: relative;
 left: -140px;
 display: inline-block;
 top: 325px;
}

.shape-10 {
 height: 0;
 border-top: 25px solid transparent;
 border-left: 50px solid #40bf80;
 border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
 position: relative;
 left: -410px;
 display: inline-block;
 top: 325px;
}

#menu h1 {
 font-size: 7rem;
 color: white;
 font-family: 'Cedarville Cursive';
 margin-left: 220px;
 position: relative;
 top: -450px;
}

.line-2 {
 background-color: #339966;
 width: 0px;
 height: 5px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 position: relative;
 top: -600px;
 left: 45px;
 transition: all 1s ease;
}

.platter {
 font-size: 2.3rem;
 font-family: 'Cedarville Cursive';
 color: #339966;
 margin-left: 60px;
}

.platter-info {
 font-size: 1.2rem;
 font-family: 'Josefin Sans';
 color: white;
 margin-left: 120px;
 margin-top: -50px;
 margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.item {
 font-family: 'Josefin Sans';
 font-size: 1.3rem;
}

.price {
 font-size: 1.3rem;
 font-family: 'Josefin Sans';
 display: block;
 margin-left: 400px;
 margin-bottom: -40px;
 position: relative;
 bottom: 40px;
}

.col-1 {
 margin-left: 200px;
 margin-top: 0px;
 position: relative;
 top: -550px;
}

.plat-4 {
 position: relative;
 left: 120px;
}

.plat-5 {
 position: relative;
 left: 75px;
}

.plat-6 {
 position: relative;
 left: 85px;
}

.info4tacos {
 position: relative;
 left: 70px;
 margin-bottom: 35px;
}

.plat-7 {
 position: relative;
 left: 100px;
}

.plat-8 {
 position: relative; 
 right: 50px;
}

.plat-9 {
 position: relative;
 left: 30px;
}

.info4breakfast {
 position: relative;
 left: 50px;
}

.col-2 {
 float: right;
 margin-top: -3185px;
 margin-right: 200px;
}

.plat-2 {
 position: relative;
 left: 70px;
 top: 15px;
}

.plat-3 {
 position: relative;
 left: 60px;
}

.right-border {
 float: right;
 transform: rotate(180deg);
 position: relative;
 top: 2400px;
 right: 10px;
}

/*HOURS*/

#hours .container {
 background-color: #339966;
 width: 100vw;
 position: relative;
 margin-top: -470px;
 clip-path: polygon(0% 4%, 5% 0%, 95% 0%, 100% 4%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
 overflow: hidden;
}

#hours h1 {
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 4rem;
 color: white;
 font-family: 'Cedarville Cursive';
 padding-bottom: 100px;
 margin-top: 0px;
 position: relative;
 bottom: 80px;
}

.day, .hour {
 text-align: center;
 background-color: white;
 font-size: 2.5rem;
 color: #666;
 padding-top: 10px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 width: 220px;
 font-family: 'Josefin Sans';
 border-right: 12px solid #40bf80;
}

.grid {
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: 270px 270px;
 grid-auto-rows: 65px;
 grid-gap: 15px;
 position: relative;
 left: 50%;
 margin-left: -272.5px;
 margin-top: -220px;
}

.move3 {
 top: 85px;
}

.move10 {
 position: relative;
 top: 265px;
}

.rotate {
 transform: rotate(180deg);
 width: 600px;
}

.hours-line, .hours-line2 {
 width: 500px;
 height: 10px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 position: relative;
 background-color: #ff4d4d;
 top: -300px;
 left: 30px;
}

.hours-line2 {
 background-color: lightgreen;
 left: 820px;
 top: -305px;
}

.lom {
 transform: rotate(-180deg);
}

/*CONTACT*/

.back-wrapper {
 background-color: #595959;
 width: 100vw;
 height: 650px;
 clip-path: polygon(0 0, 15% 15%, 85% 15%, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
 margin-top: -100px;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.contact-wrapper:before {
 content: '';
 background-color: #339966;
 width: 250px;
 height: 130px;
 position: absolute;
 left: 50%;
 margin-left: -125px;
 top: -91px;
 clip-path: polygon(15% 1%, 85% 0, 100% 30%, 100% 70%, 85% 100%, 15% 100%, 0% 70%, 0% 30%);
}

.contact-wrapper:after {
 content: '';
 background-color: #339966;
 clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 50%, 50% 100%, 0% 50%);
 width: 65px;
 height: 65px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 65px;
 left: 50%;
 margin-left: -32.5px;
}

.contact-wrapper {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
 background-color: #404040;
 position: relative;
 margin-top: -552px;
}

.loc, .con {
 flex-basis: 48%;
}

.contact-wrapper h1 {
 font-family: 'Cedarville Cursive';
 color: white;
 font-size: 5rem;
 margin-bottom: 0;
 margin-top: 0;
 text-align: center;
}

.split {
 background-color: orange;
 width: 3px;
 height: 300px;
 position: relative;
 top: 160px;
}

.upArrow {
 font-size: 2.5rem;
 color: #404040;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 1;
 left: 50%;
 top: -55px;
 margin-left: -20px;
 cursor: pointer;
 transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

.upArrow:hover {
 transform: scale(1.25);
 color: orange;
}

.to-top {
 font-family: 'Josefin Sans';
 color: #404004;
 font-size: 2rem;
 position: absolute;
 left: 50%;
 margin-left: -85px;
 font-weight: bold;
}

.phone, .email {
 color: white;
 font-size: 1.7rem;
 font-family: 'Josefin Sans';
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 0;
 margin-bottom: 0;
 margin-left: 70px;
}

textarea {
 outline: none;
 background-color: #333;
 border: none;
 margin: 15px;
 position: relative;
 left: 50%;
 margin-left: -158.75px;
 color: white;
}

input {
 margin: 20px;
 font-size: 1.25rem;
 position: relative;
 left: -95px;
 top: 10px;
 background-color: grey;
 border: none;
 border-radius: 4px;
 transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

input:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
 color: orange;
}

.review {
 font-size: 1.5rem;
 color: white;
 font-family: 'Josefin Sans';
 position: relative;
 left: 170px;
 top: -20px;
}

.fab {
 font-size: 3.3rem;
 margin-right: 15px;
 position: relative;
 left: 385px;
 top: -85px;
}

.recker {
 transform: rotate(90deg);
    width: 300px;
    height: 15px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #595959;
    left: 30px;
    top: 120px;
    border-radius: 10px;

}

.main {
 width: 400px;
    height: 20px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #595959;
    left: 80px;
    top: 100px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.rd {
 transform: rotate(90deg);
    width: 300px;
    height: 10px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #595959;
    left: 280px;
    top: 80px;
    border-radius: 10px
}

.fa-map-pin {
 font-size: 4rem;
 color: orange;
 position: relative;
 left: 290px;
 top: -35px;
}

.loc p {
 position: relative;
 color: white;
 font-family: 'Josefin Sans';
}

.con-border, .loc-border {
 position: absolute;
}

.loc-border {
 transform: rotate(180deg);
}

/*FOOTER*/

#footer .container {
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #595959;
 text-align: center;
 position: relative;
 margin-top: -54px;
 margin-bottom: 0;
}

#footer h1 {
 margin: 0;
 font-family: 'Josefin Sans';
 font-weight: bolder;
 font-size: 1.5rem;
 padding: 15px;
 color: darkgrey;
}
```

Comment: You could either upload your images to somewhere like imgur or you can use some random images found on the internet with the same size.

Comment: You've already made the animations working on the 3 buttons, try to reuse the same trick for the image slider.

Comment: oh dang your right

Comment: https://placeholder.com/